# Break big JSON into separate small JSONs based on a specific key, value pair in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, collections

I have a JSON which I created from SQL Server using JSON PATH, below is how it looks, this JSON is stored in a STRING type of variable.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Dennis Law",
      "givenName": "Dennis",
      "surname": "Law",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "dennislaw@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-IN",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Geroge West",
      "givenName": "Geroge",
      "surname": "West",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "gwest"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "PST",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "Team2"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Shaggy Nate",
      "givenName": "Shaggy",
      "surname": "Nate",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "NST",
      "extension_locale": "en-AF",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the below JSON, I have a key **extension_tenant** which is like a team, so we have values like **Team1, Team2, Team3...and so on**

I want to know if there is a way I can break this JSON based on **extension_tenant** and store it in STRING based on **extension_tenant**, so it will look like this.

Suppose all with extension_tenant = Team1 will be stored in a separate STRING,

example :

```
String Team1 = "

{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Dennis Law",
      "givenName": "Dennis",
      "surname": "Law",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "dennislaw@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-IN",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Shaggy Nate",
      "givenName": "Shaggy",
      "surname": "Nate",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "NST",
      "extension_locale": "en-AF",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    }
  ]
} ";
```

and for all with extension_tenant as Team2

```
String Team2 = "
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Geroge West",
      "givenName": "Geroge",
      "surname": "West",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "gwest"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "PST",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "Team2"
    }
  ]
} ";
```

I hope I was able to explain what I am trying to do, please suggest and approach, I am active on stackoverflow, so i will probably reply and work on suggestions immediately. I am also looking for ways to do it mean while.

Answer (score 1):

Check if following approach work for you

User.java

```
package json;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class User {
    @JsonProperty("displayName")
    private String displayName;

    @JsonProperty("givenName")
    private String givenName;

    @JsonProperty("surname")
    private String surname;

    @JsonProperty("extension_user_type")
    private String extension_user_type;

    @JsonProperty("identities")
    private List<Identity> identities;

    @JsonProperty("extension_timezone")
    private String extension_timezone;

    @JsonProperty("extension_locale")
    private String extension_locale;

    @JsonProperty("extension_tenant")
    private String extension_tenant;

    /**
     * @return the displayName
     */
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    /**
     * @param displayName
     *            the displayName to set
     */
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the givenName
     */
    public String getGivenName() {
        return givenName;
    }

    /**
     * @param givenName
     *            the givenName to set
     */
    public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
        this.givenName = givenName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the surname
     */
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param surname
     *            the surname to set
     */
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the extension_user_type
     */
    public String getExtension_user_type() {
        return extension_user_type;
    }

    /**
     * @param extension_user_type
     *            the extension_user_type to set
     */
    public void setExtension_user_type(String extension_user_type) {
        this.extension_user_type = extension_user_type;
    }

    /**
     * @return the identities
     */
    public List<Identity> getIdentities() {
        return identities;
    }

    /**
     * @param identities
     *            the identities to set
     */
    public void setIdentities(List<Identity> identities) {
        this.identities = identities;
    }

    /**
     * @return the extension_timezone
     */
    public String getExtension_timezone() {
        return extension_timezone;
    }

    /**
     * @param extension_timezone
     *            the extension_timezone to set
     */
    public void setExtension_timezone(String extension_timezone) {
        this.extension_timezone = extension_timezone;
    }

    /**
     * @return the extension_locale
     */
    public String getExtension_locale() {
        return extension_locale;
    }

    /**
     * @param extension_locale
     *            the extension_locale to set
     */
    public void setExtension_locale(String extension_locale) {
        this.extension_locale = extension_locale;
    }

    /**
     * @return the extension_tenant
     */
    public String getExtension_tenant() {
        return extension_tenant;
    }

    /**
     * @param extension_tenant
     *            the extension_tenant to set
     */
    public void setExtension_tenant(String extension_tenant) {
        this.extension_tenant = extension_tenant;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append('{');
        stringBuilder.append("\"displayName\":" + "\"" + displayName + "\",");
        stringBuilder.append("\"givenName\":" + "\"" + givenName + "\",");
        stringBuilder.append("\"surname\":" + "\"" + surname + "\",");
        stringBuilder.append("\"extension_user_type\":" + "\""
                + extension_user_type + "\",");

        if (identities != null && identities.size() > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append("\"identities\": [");
            for (Identity identity : identities) {
                stringBuilder.append(identity);
            }
            stringBuilder.append("],");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("\"extension_timezone\":" + "\""
                + extension_timezone + "\",");
        stringBuilder.append("\"extension_locale\":" + "\"" + extension_locale
                + "\",");
        stringBuilder.append("\"extension_tenant\":" + "\"" + extension_tenant
                + "\"");
        stringBuilder.append('}');
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Identity.java

```
package json;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Identity {
    @JsonProperty("signInType")
    private String signInType;

    @JsonProperty("issuerAssignedId")
    private String issuerAssignedId;

    /**
     * @return the signInType
     */
    public String getSignInType() {
        return signInType;
    }

    /**
     * @param signInType
     *            the signInType to set
     */
    public void setSignInType(String signInType) {
        this.signInType = signInType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the issuerAssignedId
     */
    public String getIssuerAssignedId() {
        return issuerAssignedId;
    }

    /**
     * @param issuerAssignedId
     *            the issuerAssignedId to set
     */
    public void setIssuerAssignedId(String issuerAssignedId) {
        this.issuerAssignedId = issuerAssignedId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append('{');
        stringBuilder.append("\"signInType\":" + "\"" + signInType + "\",");
        stringBuilder.append("\"issuerAssignedId\":" + "\"" + issuerAssignedId
                + "\"");
        stringBuilder.append('}');
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Users.java

```
package json;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Users {
    @JsonProperty("users")
    List<User> users;

    /**
     * @return the users
     */
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    /**
     * @param users
     *            the users to set
     */
    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append('{');

        if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append("\"users\": [");
            for (User user : users) {
                stringBuilder.append(user);
            }
            stringBuilder.append("]");
        }
        stringBuilder.append('}');
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Stored the json into d:/test.json

Post deserialization doing group by on extension_tenant attribute.

Converter.java

```
package json;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                false);
        Users users = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("d:/testsep.json");
            //Get Users object
            users = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Users.class);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            Map<String, String> groupByTenantmap = null;
            if (users != null) {
                //retrieve list of User object
                List<User> userList = users.getUsers();
                if (userList != null && userList.size() > 0) {
                    groupByTenantmap = new HashMap<String, String>(
                            userList.size());
                    String extension_tenant = null;
                    String value = null;
                    for (User user : userList) {
                        //populate map group by extension_tenant
                        extension_tenant = user.getExtension_tenant();
                        if (groupByTenantmap.containsKey(extension_tenant)) {
                            value = groupByTenantmap.get(extension_tenant);
                            stringBuilder.append(value).append(',')
                                    .append(user.toString());
                            groupByTenantmap.put(extension_tenant,
                                    stringBuilder.toString());
                        } else {
                            groupByTenantmap.put(extension_tenant,
                                    user.toString());
                        }
                        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
                    }
                    
                    //iterate through map and create desired json structure
                    for (Entry<String, String> entry : groupByTenantmap
                            .entrySet()) {
                        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
                        stringBuilder.append("{").append("\"users\":")
                                .append("[");
                        stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue()).append("]");
                        stringBuilder.append("}");
                        System.out.println("String " + entry.getKey() + "=\""
                                + stringBuilder.toString() + "\";");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
String Team2="{"users":[{"displayName":"Geroge West","givenName":"Geroge","surname":"West","extension_user_type":"user","identities": [{"signInType":"userName","issuerAssignedId":"gwest"}],"extension_timezone":"PST","extension_locale":"en-GB","extension_tenant":"Team2"}]}";

String Team1="{"users":[{"displayName":"Dennis Law","givenName":"Dennis","surname":"Law","extension_user_type":"user","identities": [{"signInType":"emailAddress","issuerAssignedId":"dennislaw@gmail.com"}],"extension_timezone":"VET","extension_locale":"en-IN","extension_tenant":"Team1"},{"displayName":"Shaggy Nate","givenName":"Shaggy","surname":"Nate","extension_user_type":"user","identities": [{"signInType":"userName","issuerAssignedId":"Shaggynatealpha"}],"extension_timezone":"NST","extension_locale":"en-AF","extension_tenant":"Team1"}]}";
```

Comment: I will try your approach! I got it resolved though, you solutions looks more efficient